# A silly question regarding square meters

Tags: area

Suppose we have two areas: $B$ of size $4m^2$ and $A$ of size $2m^2$.
What is the ratio between their sizes?

A simple division would yield 2, but I think that the answer is 4, as illustrated below:
[image: A 4x4 square whose area is thus the same as B's.]

Could you please clear up the confusion? (E.g. in case the latter option is correct: If a simple division gives the wrong result, how should one approach this problem?)

Comment: You are confusing length with area. The squares shown in your diagram each have an area of $2 \times 2=4m^2$, not $2m^2$

Comment: This is essentially the same mistake as the slaveboy made in Plato's dialogue [Meno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meno#Dialogue_with_Meno.27s_slave)!

Answer (score 1):

As you pose it, this is really a question about notation: $4m^2$ means four square metres, not 4 metres squared. This is to be expected: in general, $ax^2$ means $a(x)(x)$, not $(ax)(ax)$. So the area of $B$ is twice the area of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio between their *areas* is, as you said, 2. (The word "size" is a bit ambiguous, but it's most natural to interpret it as "area" in this context.)

If $A$ and $B$ are both squares, we could also ask the related (but different!) question: what is the ratio between their *side lengths*? In that case, $A$ would have side length $\sqrt{2} m$  and $B$ would have side length $2 m$, and the ratio of side lengths is $\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{2}$.